# Prove the limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $f,g,h : D \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions, $D \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let c be an accumulation point of $D$. Suppose that $$f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$$ 
>   for all $x \in D$ with $x \neq c$ and suppose 
>   $$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = \lim_{x \to c} h(x) = L \in \mathbb{R}$$ 
>   Prove that $\lim_{x \to c}g(x) = L$

I'm not really sure how to start this exercise. If someone could help me start this or give ideas, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given. We can find $\delta_1,\delta_2 > 0 $ such that if $0 < |x-c| < \delta_i $ , $i=1,2$, then

$$ L -  \epsilon < f(x) < L +  \epsilon $$

$$ L -  \epsilon  < h(x) < L +  \epsilon $$

Take $\delta = \min( \delta_1, \delta_2 ) $. then if $ 0 < |x-c| < \delta$, we have

$$ L - \epsilon < f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x) < L + \epsilon $$

which implies

$$ |g(x) - L | < \epsilon $$.

Hence, by definition, $$ \lim_{x \to c} g(x) = L $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>L-\epsilon$ and $h(c)<L+\epsilon$ for $x\in D$ with $|x-c|<\delta$. ...

Answer (score 1):

The core of the proof is this couple of inequalities:
$$g(x)-L\leq h(x)-L\leq|h(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
$$L-g(x)\leq L-f(x)\leq|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$